# InventoryClickEvent срабатывает через раз

Tags: java

```js
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.event.inventory.InventoryClickEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerDropItemEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.EventPriority;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

public class Handler implements org.bukkit.event.Listener {
    
    @EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.HIGHEST)
    public void onInventoryClick(InventoryClickEvent event)
    {
        Player player = ((Player)event.getWhoClicked());
        
        ItemStack currentItem = event.getCurrentItem();
             
        if(currentItem == null || currentItem.getType() != Material.BOOK) return;
        
        event.setCancelled(true);
 player.updateInventory();
    }
    
    @EventHandler
    public void onDropItem(PlayerDropItemEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getItemDrop().getItemStack().getType() != Material.BOOK) return;
        
        event.setCancelled(true);
    }
}
```

Моя задача - запретить игроку выбрасывать или перемещать по инвертарю определенный предмет. Например, книгу. Но функция onInventoryClick срабатывает четко через раз. Нажал - сработало. Нажал - не сработало. Нажал - сработало. И Т.Д.
Кто знает как это исправить?

Comment: Вызов события как происходит, что показывает деббагер?

Comment: Дебаггером пользоваться не выйдет. Событие вызывается spigot'ом. На то он и @EventHandler. Пробовал просто в консоль каждый раз при вызове выводить сообщение, но в этом и дело. Сообщение отправляется ровно в половине случаев